# Django ORM: Recursive many-to-many field join

Tags: python, django

I have these models:

```
class Permission(models.Model):
    per_id = models.ForeignKey("self",null=True)
    permissions = models.ManyToManyField("self", null=True)
    type = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
```

And:

```
class User(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True)
    permissions = models.ManyToManyField(Permission)
```

We have roles that have type=1823 that point to many permission with type=1822 and permission=null (Many-to-Many recursive relation), both "Roles and Permissions" store in permission table. I want to get a user permission using Django ORM.

```
User.objects.get(pk=3).permissions.filter(permissions__isnull=False).values("permission__id") "Gives only role's permissions

User.objects.get(pk=3).permissions.filter(permissions__isnull=True).values("id") "Gives only permissions
```

I wanna combine and distinct these two QuerySets in single query.

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this solved my problem :

```
Permission.objects.filter(Q(permission__user__id=3) | Q(user__id=3), type=1822).distinct()
```